# Texturing a window frame

Tags: texturing

I would like to texture a window frame that is part of a wall. Whenever I try texturing the window frame the wall gets textured with it. I want to texture the window frame without texturing the wall. I tried:

1. Selecting the window frame.
2. Clicking the **+** icon at the right side of the material properties.
3. Here is where I get stuck: I cannot give the new material a color. I would have to click the **New** button to do that but that is not mentioned in the solution.

I am using Blender version 2.82a. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hello :). This thread could help: [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/)

Comment: That did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create two materials (one for you wall, and one for the window frame). Select the window frame and create the new window frame material (click `+`, then click `Add new material`). Then, click `Assign` to assign that new material to the window sill.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, I'm guessing the window frame and the wall is one object

**1, so first you need to add material, let's say the first is for the wall**

[image]

**2, second you need to add new material here by pressing the + button**

[image]

**3, now you have an empty slot, proceed to click the  NEW button to add new material**

[image]

**4, now you have new material, you can name it anything you want**

[image]

and you notice the frame and the wall still have the same colour, which means you need to select which is the frame

**5. Go to edit mode by pressing TAB while clicking on the object and selecting the window frame faces**

[image]

**6. now press the button assign, to assign the current material to the selected face of the mesh**

[image]

**7. now you have an object with 2 different materials, one for the wall and one for the window frame**

[image]